# Best User Experience when navigating between 2 Lists (Fragment / Activity)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, user-experience, android-recyclerview

This question is more my way of gauging a better understanding of the "Proper" way to handle this content flow instead of just "whatever works" or the "quickest" solution to code. Im looking for the best on performance and user experience.

### The situation:

So my main activity handles my NavigationDrawer and is the basis of the app. The initial view that is loaded (navitem 0) is a Fragment which contains a RecyclerView(custom adapter, list item model, view holder). This list displays data pulled from an XML file and is returned as an Arraylist of `Topic` objects (each containing 3 strings and an array of `Issue` objects).

The array of `Topic` objects are used to populate the listitem w/ a `title`, `desecription` and `image_name` strings. (Not using the `Issue` array yet).

### Here is where you come in ...

I know need to handle the click event on the `Topic` and display a new list (w/ different adapter) of the specific `Issue` object array for that `Topic`.

I'd like to know if its better to replace the current fragment w/ a new fragment for handling the `Issue` data. Or would it be better to launch a new activity to display the `Issue` list data.

Keep in mind, i want to ensure that navigation up will return the user to the previous view. ie. when clicking a `Topic` you should get the `Issues` for that topic. When going back, the TopicFragment should be displayed w/ its initial list.

### If this is confusing you?

The core part of this question is needing to know the proper navigational way of displaying a List that when clicked needs to display another List specific to the parent object. Is fragment to fragment handled by callbacks in the MainActivity the best way, or is Intent'ing to another activity to handle the 2nd list better?

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is:  depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  Neither of them is necessarily wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use a `Fragment` or an `Activity` to display the second list, it doesn't matter from a performance standpoint. If I were you, I'd use an `Activity`: it is always better to use a `Fragment` only in situations that require the explicit use of `Fragment`s (such as a `FragmentTabHost` or a `ViewPager`).

But I do have another suggestion for you. Instead of going to another list, why not display your `Issue` objects as the child items of an `ExpandableListView`, and the `Topic` objects as the parent items ? Then when the user clicks on an `Issue` child item, go to the detail page containing details of that `Issue` object. To me, the List->Detail pattern is a far more familiar idiom than a List->List->Detail flow. Its what `ExpandableListView` was made for.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, This was exactly the confirmation i needed.  I will look into the ExpandableListView option as i didnt even think about it (makes good sense to use though). However until then the transition to a new activity seems to be the more reasonable option.

Comment: Here some food for thought, If i went the activity route, should i create the activity w/ the list and then intent to another activity to display the detail view? or should i use a fragment to display the list and/or the detail view?

Comment: If you plan to support tablets, you could have a multi-pane layout in which the list & detail views are shown side-by-side. In this case you'd have to use a single `Activity` which would show a list `Fragment` and a detail `Fragment` side-by-side within the same `Activity` **on a tablet**, and a normal list->detail flow **on a handset**.

Comment: Awesome that'll do, thanks again for the great feedback.